# Why adding a PHP script to sudoers file does not work?

Tags: php, bash, nginx, permissions, ubuntu-18.04

It seems adding a PHP script to sudoers file has no effect, whereas adding a bash script allows you to run it as root.
To demonstrate that, assume we have the following three scripts:

**/var/www/literal.php**

```
exec('sudo whoami', $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output, $return_var);
```

**/var/www/indirect.php**

```
exec('sudo /var/www/script.sh', $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output, $return_var);
```

**/var/www/script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(whoami)"
```

Also assume we have the following lines in the sudoers file (added through visudo of course):

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/literal.php
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/script.sh
```

Browsing to http://localhost/literal.php we get:

```
array(0) { }   
int(1)
```

Going to http://localhost/indirect.php however we get this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(4) "root"
}
int(0)
```

Obviously, the sudoer line worked for the shell script, but did not work for the PHP script. Is this an intentional, by-design limitation, or could I have hope to get it to work? If so, where should I look for causes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sudoers file you specify precise command to be run. So `/var/www/literal.php` at least should have a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/php` and launched in shell as is by typing `/var/www/literal.php` then `Enter` in order to be run by `sudo`.

When you run that same script "via browser", this isn't happening. Instead the PHP-FPM process is interpreting the script (NGINX passes its filename to PHP-FPM). You may say (although this isn't exactly like this) that the real command being run is more or less `/sbin/php-fpm /var/www/literal.php`, which of course won't match to what you have in sudoers file.

Whatever command that you want to be run as `sudo` via PHP script, you need to be placing in sudoers exactly as it will be run when prefixed with `sudo`, e.g.

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/script.sh
```

Then:

> exec('sudo /usr/bin/whoami', $output, $return_var);

Will run successfully when the script is accessed from the browser.

An off-topic, but you should *not* be running anything as webserver user. The `www-data` is NGINX/Apache user. The scripts should run under a dedicated "website specific" user, for security purpose. More on that [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be).

Comment: +1 Thanks. I was worried that would be the case. I could confirm this by a small test: When I added the shebang to literal.php and made the file executable with `chmod +x /var/www/literal.php` I did get the expected output by calling it in terminal with `sudo /var/www/literal.php`. Furthermore, a call like `sudo /var/www/script.sh` works; but running `sudo bash /var/www/script.sh` we get prompted for sudo password.

Answer (score 0):

With the explanation provided by @DanilaVershinin in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63724164/66580), I thought a recursive approach might work. I tried it and it did! So here it is:

Our PHP script calls itself in CLI if it detects it is being called via the web server:
**/var/www/control.php**

```
if (PHP_SAPI !== "cli") {
    exec('sudo /usr/bin/php /var/www/control.php param1 param2', $output, $return_var);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump(PHP_SAPI, $output, $return_var);
    exit();
}

exec('whoami', $output, $return_var);
var_dump(PHP_SAPI, $argv, $output, $return_var);
```

And this is the line we need in our sudoers file:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/php /var/www/control.php *
```

The output we get by going to http://localhost/control.php shows the calling user is root and we have received the parameters (the `*` at the end of sudoers line is to still match when we have parameters.)

The important concern with this is the security risk. I will share a version of this on Github where the security risk has been mitigated and will provide a link here.