# PHP script will not run bash command

Tags: php, bash

I am having trouble getting my PHP script to run a bash command/script. Here is an export of my PHP script (it is triggered when a HTML form is submitted):

```
}
chdir('/usr/local/sim/');
shell_exec('killall -9 sim');
shell_exec(./write-sims.sh');
chdir('/var/www/html/');
shell_exec('php -f test.php');
?>
```

I know that this PHP script is running okay as the 'killall -9 sim' command is executed as expected along with the 'write-sims.sh' script.

I put my bash command inside a PHP script as a test to see if that would work but it doesn't, 'test.php' is as follows:

```
<?php
shell_exec("find /usr/local/sim/data -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.conf' -exec sh -c '/usr/local/sim/build/src/sim --daemon --config {} &' \;");
?>
```

When I run test.php manually via cli it runs fine however whenever it is called by the first php script it doesn't run.

I have tried switching things around by putting the bash command in a .sh script and calling that from the first php script and also adding the bash command itself inside the first php script but neither work however I don't get any errors in the nginx error log which seems to suggest the script is running okay without errors.

Any idea why this is not running but runs fine when I do it manually? Thanks!

Comment: As what user are you running CLI? Sounds like a permission problem to me

Comment: Can you var_dump() the shell_exec return value please?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#refsect1-function.shell-exec-examples

Comment: @DarkBee I am running cli as root

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why adding a PHP script to sudoers file does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692354/why-adding-a-php-script-to-sudoers-file-does-not-work)

Comment: ^This is if you are running a linux distro though

Comment: Running a server execution command from an HTML form submission sounds absolutely horrendous. Enjoy having your server compromised.

Comment: Yeah I am running Ubuntu. What I am not sure of is why are the other bash scripts running okay? As I mentioned all bash scripts run without issue when I start them manually but only this one seems to fail when called by the PHP script, the other two are okay. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Martin yes I am aware of the security concerns. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well yeah, you are running them as `root` on the `cli`. Your PHP process doesn't run as `root`, more something like `www-data`, and prolly doesn't have enough permissions to execute bash scripts `.bs`

Comment: @DarkBee yeah the first PHP script is owned by user `www-data` and all the bash scripts are owned by `root` however how does this explain 2 of the 3 bash commands/scripts running okay but the third failing?

Comment: I have also tried adding all bash commands into the same script and it is called as expected by the PHP script but seems to fail on the one command mentioned above in 'test.php'