Impossible to call a bash file with shell_exec with PHP
I am managing a Rocky Linux 8 server.
I would like to be able to execute bash files from a webpage.
Here is the information about the structure:

The PHP file is in /var/www/mywebsite.com/index.php with (apache:apache CH644)
My bash file is in /root/test.sh (root:root CH755)
In php.ini file shell_exec has been removed from disable_functions

Here is the content of test.sh file:
#!/bin/bash echo 'hello';
1/ From my console as root user, when I execute "/root/test.sh", it's working fine!
2/ From my PHP file, if I run the following code, it's working too.
$test = shell_exec('date'); echo $test;
3/ From my PHP file, if I run the following code, it's not working :
$test = shell_exec('/root/test.sh'); or $test = shell_exec('sh /root/test.sh'); or $test = shell_exec('/usr/bin/sh /root/test.sh'); echo $test;
It's not working and it is so frustrating...
I have been searching for hours and I do not find any solution.
Would you please help me solve this issue.
Maybe is the Apache Configuration that is wrong...
Thank you so much!

The Apache user cannot access the home folder of user root, i.e. /root. You should not put the script in that folder.

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692354/why-adding-a-php-script-to-sudoers-file-does-not-work

For future reference "not working" isn't a useful problem description. It doesn't tell us what your code did or didn't do. Always report the exact behaviour you experience including any error messages or unexpected output. Then it's 100% clear what is happening.

Thank you for your comments, it helped me to find a solution that I am going to post

I found a solution by adding she bash file in the web folder with the apache:apache permission. Using shell_exe and calling a bash file outside de web project doesn't work.
The structure that I use is the following:

/var/www/mywebsite.com/app/test.sh
/var/www/mywebsite.com/www/index.php

This will protect my bash files as the folder "app" is not accessible from the web. Also the good syntax that works for me in my index.php is:
$test = shell_exec('sh ../app/test.sh');
echo $test;

I hope it will help some other people.
Thanks for you help!
